# Bad Request - Request Too Long (IdentityServer4)

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I have an IdentityServer4 that when users have about 10 roles the cookie seems to grow exponentially. Everytime I try to log in now I get greeted with a 400 error request too long due to how large the cookie is.

The cookie I receive is split up to 5 chunks of around 4008 in size:

[image: cookies]

these cookies seem to be set on the signin-oidc endpoint of the application.

I am using the default cookie settings in identity server - no changes there.

Any ideas what could cause these cookies to grow so quickly? The size of the Id_token and Access_token seem to be substantially smaller than these cookies.

Edit: Each role I assign to the user in addition seems to add 400 size to the last cookie in the chunk which seems very large to me?

Edit 2: I am using a custom profile service would this impact the size of the final cookie:

```
    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var subjectId = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(subjectId);

        if (user == null) return;

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim("username", user.UserName),
            new Claim("email", user.Email),
            new Claim("firstname", user.FirstName),
            new Claim("lastname", user.LastName)
        };

        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim("role", role));
        }

        var userClaims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
        foreach (var userClaim in userClaims)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(userClaim.Type, userClaim.Value));
        }

        context.IssuedClaims = claims;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the application authentication cookie that is growing, not identity server cookie.

And you assumed well, cookie is growing because **it encrypts all the claims**, including roles in the cookie to persist them between server calls.

Alternative solution would be to configure IdentityServer to pass only minimal amount of user data that is required throughout the application lifetime on initial login. Everything else, that you might need "at certain point", you could retrieve via backend call to **user-info endpoint** using `access_token`. Drawback of this approach is that managing `access_token` lifetime then becomes an issue, because, unlike cookie, it does not have rolling expiration.

Other option would be to **enable session for your web app**, and to store cookie data into the server-side session storage, instead of the cookie itself.

Update:

Regarding your `GetProfileDataAsync`, it loads all claims, which is fine, but then you configure in `IdentityResources` configuration which filters claims you actually want to pass to the client. Configuration of IdentityServer is too big topic to discuss in details in SO question.

Comment: Thanks for your response, very informative! ```Other option would be to enable session for your web app, and to store cookie data into the session storage, instead of the cookie itself.``` - is this something that would be configured as part of the client configuration when adding cookie and oidc?

Comment: Something I forgot to mention was that this issue doesn't seem to happen with our instance of IdentityServer3 which has made this issue a bit more perplexing considering the user claims for all our users are the same across both apps and they both handle cookies within the client in the same way.

Comment: Yes, it can be configured. I think within cookie configuration. Just to make it clear, I ment server side session storage (SQL, or whatever). Not session storage of the browser. There are hooks into cookie authentication configuration for that.

Comment: Regarding IdentityServer3, only difference that I can think of right now, is that configuration was slighlty different. Perhepas v3 is emmiting smaller number of claims by default during login? Client application cookie should have been handled in the same way.

Comment: Ah I see, my apologies. I will investigate into SQL Session storage. I am using a custom ProfileService to pass the user claims through. Perhaps I am using inproper configuration. I will edit the question with that code.

Comment: just compared claims across IdSvr3 & 4 and although they have the same name all the roles in the newer identity server are prefixed with the following: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role. I guess this is what is contributing to the size of the cookie.

Comment: That's correct. You can use shorter OpenID style names (just `role`) and swap the role claim mapping name in the client application. One way by configuring `TokenValidationParameter.RoleClaimType` to "role" value.

Comment: I see, thanks very much for your help. I think I've asked a lot more than the original question, so I appreciate the additional explanation.

Comment: "Alternative solution would be to configure IdentityServer to pass only minimal amount of user data that is required throughout the application lifetime on initial login." how do you do this? There was no actionable demonstration of this.

Comment: @DarthScitus We are talking about user data, which depends on your application. If you don't need user's first-name, last-name, phone-number, email,... don't load them into `id_token`. Those values are not there by default, they are added by programmer or admin. So if you would have added them yourself, you would already know how to remove them.